# Creating a button click counter using Laravel, Ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The button counter on the homepage(after logging in) is supposed to increment count each time the button is pressed. Instead on pressing the button my code is redirecting to the authentication page for failed authentications. The Ajax code does not seem to be posting to the page. I dont understand why this is happening! Been stuck with this for 2 days. Can anyone help me out? I am relatively new to this.

Here is the View(html code). Its called like.blade.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <?php $count=1; ?>
    <div>
        <form action="sessions/{count}" method="get" />
        <input type=submit name="count" value="Counter" />
        <br/>This button has been clicked
        <span id="counter"><?php echo $count; ?></span> times.
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
             $( '#counter').click(function(){ 
                $.ajax({ 
                    type : 'POST', 
                    url: "sessions.{count}", 
                    data: like:like, 
                    dataType: 'text', 
                    async: true 
                    success: function update_text(data) { 
                        alert( "Counter clicked"); 
                    };
                });                         
                return false;
              }); 
          }); 
    </script>
< /body>
</html >
```

This is the method where I am incrementing the counter and returning it :

```
Route::get('sessions.like', function () {
    return View::make('sessions.like');
});

Route::get('sessions/{count}', function ($count) {
    if (isset($count)) {
        $count = $count + 1;
    } else {
        $count = 1;
    }

    return View::make('sessions.like')->with('sessions', $count);
});
```

Comment: Start by looking in browser dev tools console (F12). You have  a few syntax errors that will cause code not to run

Comment: Yes, the code has some syntax errors... It's the code you're implementing atm?

Comment: your input type should be set to button, not submit, 
also don't forget to  have a form close every time you initiate form::open();

Comment: your data should also be enclosed with {} since your sending a valued pair/array

Comment: on your route you shouldnt return a view since... instead return an object or a variable.. use return array('count',$count);

Comment: success: function(data){ $('#counter').innerHTML(data['count']); }

Comment: @charlietfl,llGala,melvnberd - I made the changes you guys suggested, My Dev tools currently shows : Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated. After making the changes, the button counter on click doesnt do anything. The page remains the same.

Comment: Is the data i have passed supposed to be the variable count? What should i be passing there? I am a little confused. And is the url for ajax supposed to be the same as the url for the button counter? Really need help on this.

Comment: @llGala - What do you mean by atm?

Comment: the warning is probably you set `async: false` which is bad. The url in code shown was another area of concern. I don't know the php framework you are using but would look at what that value actually is and see if it is what is expected

Comment: i think `sessions.{count}` should be `sessions/{count}`

Comment: @charlietfl - That did not work. Anything else that could be wrong?